# Is there a way to apply the default "disabled" style on a text input without actually disabling the input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Pretty straightforward. I want the text input to look disabled (browser's default disabled style) but without actually being disabled so I can still sell it trough post.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to send it throung post you can make the input field as hidden instead of making it look disabled

```
<input type="hidden" value="yourvalue">
```

Its not direct way to make it look disabled as disabled input field looks different in every other browser...

Comment: Yeah I thought about that and it would complicate matters a lot. I thought there might be a way to do it in a more simple matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display data that the user can't change, and then send it to a server with a POST then include it as a  hidden `<input>`

```
<input type=hidden name=myHiddenValue value="My Hidden Value">
```

It will appear as `$_POST['myHiddenValue']` when the form is submitted.

If you need to display it too then you can include it in your HTML, just not as an `<input>` field.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. The input changes from disabled to enabled based on a multitude of factors. It's not just a value that I don't want the user to change. I could just set it as readonly (and I do) but I want to convey it to the user in a visual manner.

Comment: Then I think you need to add a lot more detail to your question.

Comment: I don't want stackoverflow to fix my problem, I just wanted to know if there's a fast way to apply the default disabled style and it seems like the answer is no.